# Are they tangent to each other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I show that these two equations are tangent to each other?

$$x-2y=10$$
$$x^2+y^2=20$$

When I sketched and plotted these equations it does show that they are tangent to each other, but I can't show it algebraically.

Comment: AFAIK, equations can **not** be tangent. However, curves, described by those equations, can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Let's find the ordinate of the intersection(s)

$$20=(2y+10)^2+y^2\iff5y^2+40y+80=0$$

$\implies5(y+4)^2=0$

Alternatively

Use the fact:

The perpendicular distance to a tangent from the center $=$ radius

Answer (score 1):

The equations only have one solution, $(2,-4)$, so the curves have one intersection point, so they must be tangent (because one is a circle and one is a line).

To find this solution, we can substitute.

$$x = 2y + 10$$
$$(2y+10)^2 + y^2 = 20$$
$$(4y^2 + 40y + 100 + y^2 = 20)$$
$$5y^2 + 40y + 80 = 0$$
Solving this quadratic gives $y=-4$. Substitute back into the other equation to obtain $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: the line meets the circle at the point $(2,-4)$ as seen by solving the two equations together. The slope of the line is $-\frac 1 2$. To find the slope of the tangent line to the circle at $(2,-4)$ you have to find the derivative using the equation $y =-\sqrt {2-x^{2}}$.  (minus sign because $y<0$ near the point $(2,-4)$). If you carry out this differentiation yo will see that the slope is again $-\frac 1 2$.

Answer (score 0):

***HINT***

The first depicts a line in $\mathbb{R^2}$, the second a circle.

If you solve the system of the two equations you will be able to deduce-based on the presense and/or number of solutions-which of the three holds:
 

$i)$ No common points.

$ii)$ A sinlge common point (which means the line is tangent to the circle).

$iii)$ Two common points (the line crosses the circle).

Comment: It's worth emphasising the presented set of three cases applies to this particular configuration of a line and a circle, not for any lines, defined by any set of equations. For other curves the situation may differ. For example, A line and a parabola may have one point in common, which is either a tangency point or an intersection. If two ellipses have two points in common, they either touch or cross one another in both points; but with 3 common points, one is a tangency point while other two are intersections. And so on...

Comment: @CiaPan Indeed. I considered this a given.

Comment: I know, and I point that out as a minor ambiguity, rather than as a hole in the solution. I consider the problem as a school-level, hence I feel like underlining the educational value of the answers. In such cases solutions should be both complete and explicit, so they won't suggest any general level of application if they actually apply to a specific problem only. Or rather should distinct the general part from the specific one (like: solving algebraic equations and concluding on geometric facts from the specific set of possible solutions and configurations in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The second equation is that of a circle centered at the origin. A line is tangent to a circle iff the distance of the line from the circle’s center is equal to the circle’s radius. Using a standard formula, this distance is $${10\over\sqrt{1^2+2^2}} = 2\sqrt 5.$$ The circle’s radius is $\sqrt{20}=2\sqrt5$, so the line is indeed tangent to the circle.